# Unmarshalling Parameterized URL String Return Type with Rest Template

Tags: java, resttemplate

I'm running an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST and getting the following as the response.

```
response=3&responsetext=1006: The specified transaction in the request is not allowed: REJECTED CONTACT CUST SERV
REFID:1202053070&authcode=&transactionid=&avsresponse=&cvvresponse=&orderid=&type=sale&response_code=300&masked_merchant_number=
```

Currently, I'm capturing the response as a String from the `RestTemplate.postForEntity` method.

How can I capture this response into an object/map? A map would be ideal since the parameters tend to change according success/failure responses.

Answer (score 0):

For now I built the following method to manually extract the values to a map.

```
private Map<String, String> buildResponseMapFromString(String response) {
        Map<String, String> saleResponse = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            String[] responseArray = response.split("&");
            for (String s : responseArray) {
                String[] keyValue = s.split("=");
                if (keyValue.length == 2) {
                    saleResponse.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
                } else {
                    saleResponse.put(keyValue[0], "");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error while parsing response map from Response String", e);
        }
        return saleResponse;
}
```

If there's a better, elegant solution, please do go ahead.